# Already have an associated managed connection error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

The root cause is

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: Already have an associated managed connection
```

If anyone can help me in understanding the cause of the problem. Please feel free to ask for further details. 
One  possible cause that I can think of is  the section in which I am getting this exception I and doing @JoinColumn to join two table and get result to display. What precaution should I take to avoid this.

```
    package com.next.domain;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.AUTO;
import static org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals;
import static org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode;
import static org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name="answers")
@XmlRootElement
public class Answer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long mId;
    private Long mQuizId;

    @Size(max=1000, message="\'Description\' must be less than 1000 characters.")
    private String mContent;

    private Date mRegDate;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        mId = id;
    }

    @Column(name="quiz_id")
    public Long getQuizId() {
        return mQuizId;
    }

    public void setQuizId(Long quizId) {
        mQuizId = quizId;
    }

    @Column(name="content")
    public String getContent() {
        return mContent;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        mContent = content;
    }

    @Column(name="reg_date")
    public Date getRegDate() {
        return mRegDate;
    }

    public void setRegDate(Date regDate) {
        mRegDate = regDate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return reflectionEquals(this, obj);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return reflectionHashCode(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return reflectionToString(this);
    }
}







package com.next.domain;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.AUTO;
import static org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals;
import static org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode;
import static org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name="quizzes")
@XmlRootElement
public class Quiz implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long mId;

    private Integer mSection;

    private Long mAnswerId;

    @NotEmpty(message="\'Title\' must not be empty.")
    @Size(max=64, message="\'Title\' must be less than 64 characters.")
    private String mTitle;

    @Size(max=256, message="\'Question\' must be less than 256 characters.")
    private String mContent;

    @Size(max=256, message="\'Description\' must be less than 256 characters.")
    private String mDescription;

    private List<Answer> mAnswers;

    private Date mRegDate;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        mId = id;
    }

    @Column(name="section")
    public Integer getSection() {
        return mSection;
    }

    public void setSection(Integer mSection) {
        this.mSection = mSection;
    }

    @Column(name="answer_id")
    public Long getAnswerId() {
        return mAnswerId;
    }

    public void setAnswerId(Long answer_id) {
        mAnswerId = answer_id;
    }

    @Column(name="title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }

    @Column(name="content")
    public String getContent() {
        return mContent;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        mContent = content;
    }

    @Column(name="description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return mDescription;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        mDescription = description;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name="quiz_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
        return mAnswers;
    }

    public void setAnswers(List<Answer> answers) {
        mAnswers = answers;
    }

    @Column(name="reg_date")
    public Date getRegDate() {
        return mRegDate;
    }

    public void setRegDate(Date regDate) {
        mRegDate = regDate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return reflectionEquals(this, obj);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return reflectionHashCode(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return reflectionToString(this);
    }
}







       package com.next.persistence;

    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    import com.next.domain.Answer;
    import com.next.domain.Quiz;
    import com.next.domain.QuizSubmission;

    @Repository("quizDao")
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
    public class QuizDaoImpl implements QuizDao {
        private static final String QUIZ_SELECT_CLAUSE = "select new map(q.id as id, q.title as title, q.regDate as regDate)";
        private static final String ANSWER_SELECT_CLAUSE = "select new map(a.id as id, a.content as content)";

        @PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
        private EntityManager em;

        @Override
        public void addQuiz(Quiz quiz) {
            em.persist(quiz);
        }

        @Override
        public void saveQuiz(Quiz quiz) {
            em.merge(quiz);
        }

        @Override
        public void deleteQuiz(long id) {
            try {
                em.remove(getQuiz(id));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ie) {
                return;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Quiz getQuiz(long id) {
            Quiz quiz = null;

            try {
                quiz = em.find(Quiz.class, id);
            } catch (NoResultException e) {}        

            return quiz;
        }

        @Override
        public void addAnswer(Answer answer) {
            em.persist(answer);
        }

        @Override
        public void saveAnswer(Answer answer) {
            em.merge(answer);
        }

        @Override
        public void deleteAnswer(long id) {
            try {
                em.remove(getAnswer(id));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ie) {
                return;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Answer getAnswer(long id) {
            Answer answer = null;

            try {
                answer = em.find(Answer.class, id);
            } catch (NoResultException e) {}        

            return answer;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public List<Map<String, Object>> getAnswers(long quizId) {
            return (List<Map<String, Object>>) em.createQuery(ANSWER_SELECT_CLAUSE + " from Answer a where a.quizId = :quizId")
                    .setParameter("quizId", quizId)
                    .getResultList();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public List<Map<String, Object>> getQuizzes(int section) {
            return (List<Map<String, Object>>) em.createQuery(QUIZ_SELECT_CLAUSE + " from Quiz q where q.section = :section order by q.regDate desc")
                    .setParameter("section", section)
                    .getResultList();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public List<Map<String, Object>> getQuizzesDetails(int section) {
            return (List<Map<String, Object>>) em.createQuery("select q from Quiz q where q.section = :section order by q.regDate desc")
                    .setParameter("section", section)
                    .getResultList();
        }

        @Override
        public Answer getAnswerByQuizId(long quizId) {
            Answer answer = null;

            try {
                answer = em.find(Answer.class, quizId);
            } catch (NoResultException e) {

            }
            return answer;
        }

        @Override
        public void addQuizSubmission(QuizSubmission quizSubmission) {
            em.persist(quizSubmission);
        }

        @Override
        public void saveQuizSubmission(QuizSubmission quizSubmission) {
            em.merge(quizSubmission);
        }

        @Override
        public void deleteQuizSubmission(long id) {
            try {
                em.remove(getQuiz(id));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ie) {
                return;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public QuizSubmission getQuizSubmission(long id) {
            QuizSubmission quizSubmission = null;

            try {
                quizSubmission = em.find(QuizSubmission.class, id);
            } catch (NoResultException e) {}        

            return quizSubmission;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public List<Map<String, Object>> getQuizSubmissions(long quizId) {
            return (List<Map<String, Object>>) em.createQuery("select qs from QuizSubmission qs where qs.quizId = :quizId order by qs.date desc")
                    .setParameter("quizId", quizId)
                    .getResultList();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public List<QuizSubmission> getQuizSubmissions(String date) {
            /*return em.createNativeQuery("SELECT `id`, `quiz_id`, `answer_id`, `date` FROM `quizzes_submissions` WHERE DATE(`date`) = :date")
                    .setParameter("date", date )
                    .getResultList();*/

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date startDate = null;
            Date endDate = null;
            try {
                startDate = format.parse(date.trim()+" 00:00:00");
                endDate = format.parse(date.trim()+" 23:59:59");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return em.createQuery("select qs from QuizSubmission qs WHERE qs.date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")
                    .setParameter("startDate", startDate)
                    .setParameter("endDate", endDate)
                    .getResultList();
        }
    }
```

My controller calls the getQuizzes(int section) of the QuizDaoImpl so that all the quizzes can be displayed.

My observation :**The complete thing works fine with fresh deployment the problem occurs after a period of 6-8 hrs once the database is ideal for a long time**

```
root cause

org.hibernate.TransactionException: Already have an associated managed connection
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:65)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1309)
org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:57)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.enlistInCurrentTransaction(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:421)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.doJoinTransaction(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:398)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:356)
sun.proxy.$Proxy150.createQuery(Unknown Source)
com.next.persistence.QuizDaoImpl.getQuizzes(QuizDaoImpl.java:102)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor358.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
sun.proxy.$Proxy163.getQuizzes(Unknown Source)
com.next.service.QuizServiceImpl.getQuizzes(QuizServiceImpl.java:92)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor357.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
sun.proxy.$Proxy164.getQuizzes(Unknown Source)
com.next.mvc.HomeController.showListPage(HomeController.java:308)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor356.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

Comment: Please post the code where the exception ocurres and the code of the metods that invoking this code.

Comment: Hi Ralph,
Thanks for for your quick response I have edited the same post with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the @PersistenceContext annotation. I had :

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

and I replaced it with :

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you already have a running transaction on your JDBC connection.

There are good chances that the previous transaction didn't ends properly : you didn't commit it , or you din't rollback it... and so this previous transaction is still *running* when you try to start a new one: this is not allowed.

So look carefully at the logs BEFORE the stackstrace you have posted to see what's going one with the previous transaction. (enable transaction logging if you don't see anything relevant)

Comment: Hi ben
I have edited the post and removed the stack trace with my code. If you can just look into it again. If you want I can put the stack trace again.

Comment: Hi ben thanks for reply. do you think it's because we are using **PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED**

Comment: It's possible indeed. According my experience ExtendedPersistenceContext is something quite difficult to use... so be sure it's a real need before using it. (sometimes people start using it because it seems to easily solve some "entity detached" issues, but in the end it make everything far more complex)

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your extended persistence context in a singleton bean (@Repository QuizzDaoImpl). An extendedPC makes sense in a Session scoped bean. It's purpose is to "stay alive" between transaction (and keeping it's entities managed even outside tx boundaries) and *join* the current tx when it exists. I've no ideas how an extendedPC behaves in a singleton bean (entities are shared between all threads and all sessions ???)

Comment: Hi Ben thanks. yes that was the problem. we just remove ExtendedPersistenceContext and it works.