# HikariCP configuration to auto close bad DB connections

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hikaricp

I have a spring boot application connecting to MS SQL Server. HikariCP is used for DS. In test environment the SQL server DB is restarted every night for some reason (I don't know). Once the DB is restarted until I restart the application, I see the following exceptions. I would like the connection to be reset without restarting the application. Any help to avoid this error is appreciated

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Already have an associated managed connection
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1771) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:64) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.enlistInCurrentTransaction(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:398) ~[spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.doJoinTransaction(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:376) ~[spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:327) ~[spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.joinTransaction(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaConsumer$1.doInTransaction(JpaConsumer.java:97) ~[camel-jpa-2.15.2.1.jar!/:2.15.2..1]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaConsumer.poll(JpaConsumer.java:94) ~[camel-jpa-2.15.2..1.jar!/:2.15.2..1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar!/:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar!/:2.15.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Already have an associated managed connection
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1471) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar!/:4.3.10.Final]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Add the properties for checking the connection validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Camel Jpa Component to poll data from db. I had to use sharedEntityManager option available in Camel 2.16 to resolve this.

http://camel.apache.org/jpa.html

The same question was ported in HikariCP forum.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hikari-cp/NpBflCtAm4A

Other helpful links: [Already have an associated managed connection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756804/already-have-an-associated-managed-connection-error)